# Mostrar imágenes desde PHP en <div>

Tags: php, imagen

He tratado de buscar solución a este problema por varios caminos y no sé exactamente qué está fallando.

Estamos implementando una plataforma para subir imágenes en 360 grados y que cualquier persona pueda subir para verlas en línea, compartir, etc. Esto con la idea de tener un lugar donde subir nuestras propias imágenes además de Facebook.

**El problema es el siguiente:**

Algunas veces todo va bien y de pronto, por alguna extraña razón, no se ve nada, no muestra la galería.

El archivo es un PHP llamado `plataforma360.php` y por el momento más HTML5 que PHP. Estamos iniciando, para el caso de este archivo la idea general es que al ingresar el usuario vea las últimas imágenes agregadas.

Anexo el código PHP. De momento es un poco bruto, después crearemos un array con las imágenes aleatorias para mostrarlas en cada `<div>`. Posteriormente el usuario, al hacer click en la imagen, podría ver la imagen en 360 y rotar con el ratón como acá:

http://conecta-leon.com.mx/360/demo/basico-fotografia-y-presentacion-modelaje-360-grados-leon-gto.html

O acá donde se carga en un modal:

http://conecta-leon.com.mx/360/

Y arrastrar en dispositivos móviles.

Pero si no logramos resolver porque a veces se muestran y a veces no, no podremos avanzar, quizá algo estamos haciendo mal y no es el camino correcto

```
<?php
$total = "11"; // Numero total de imágenes
$extension = ".jpg";// Definimos la extension, puede ser .jpg, gif, bmp, etc.
$carpeta = "images/random";//Carpeta con las imagenes
$start = "1";
$random = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random2 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random3 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random4 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random5 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random6 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random7 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random8 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random9 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random10 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random11 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random12 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random13 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random14 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random15 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random16 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random17 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random18 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random19 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random20 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random21 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random22 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random23 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random24 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random25 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$image_name1 = $random . $extension;
$image_name2 = $random2 . $extension;
$image_name3 = $random3 . $extension;
$image_name4 = $random4 . $extension;
$image_name5 = $random5 . $extension;
$image_name6 = $random6 . $extension;
$image_name7 = $random7 . $extension;



 echo '<img src="'.$carpeta."/".$image_name1.'">'."\n";
?>
```

```html
<?php
$total = "11"; // Numero total de imagenes
$extension = ".jpg";// Definimos la extension, puede ser .jpg, gif, bmp, etc.
$carpeta = "images/random";//Carpeta con las imagenes
// De aqui para abajo no es necesario modificar nada
$start = "1";
$random = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random2 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random3 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random4 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random5 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random6 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random7 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random8 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random9 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random10 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random11 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random12 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random13 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random14 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random15 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random16 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random17 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random18 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random19 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random20 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random21 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random22 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random23 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random24 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$random25 = mt_rand($start, $total);
$image_name1 = $random . $extension;
$image_name2 = $random2 . $extension;
$image_name3 = $random3 . $extension;
$image_name4 = $random4 . $extension;
$image_name5 = $random5 . $extension;
$image_name6 = $random6 . $extension;
$image_name7 = $random7 . $extension;
$image_name8 = $random8 . $extension;
$image_name9 = $random9 . $extension;
$image_name10 = $random10 . $extension;
$image_name11 = $random11 . $extension;
$image_name12 = $random12 . $extension;
$image_name13 = $random13 . $extension;
$image_name14 = $random14 . $extension;
$image_name15 = $random15 . $extension;
$image_name16 = $random16 . $extension;
$image_name17 = $random17 . $extension;
$image_name18 = $random18 . $extension;
$image_name19 = $random19 . $extension;
$image_name20 = $random20 . $extension;
$image_name21 = $random21 . $extension;
$image_name22 = $random22 . $extension;
$image_name23 = $random23 . $extension;
$image_name24 = $random24 . $extension;
$image_name25 = $random25 . $extension;


 echo '<img src="'.$carpeta."/".$image_name1.'">'."\n";
?>
```

El ejemplo en vivo acá, pueden refrescar y en algunas ocasiones simplemente no muestra las imágenes:

http://conecta-leon.com.mx/360/plataforma360.php

Dejo también unas capturas. Si a alguien se le ocurre que puede estar mal, muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

[![Captura de pantalla mostrando la galería][1]][1]

[image: Sin tocar el código solo refrescando, ya no muestra la galería]

Y anexo el mismo archivo en txt para que pueda ser explorado plataforma360.txt. en la raíz de /360 del dominio

La carpeta con los thumbs esta en /360/images/random/
Muchas gracias a todos y si a alguien le sirve el código completo lo dejaremos en github y lo estaremos actualizando con las mejoras.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Veo que es tu primera pregunta. Deberías proporcionarnos un [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Un ejemplo mínimo que pudiéramos usar para reproducir tu problema. No necesitamos el proyecto ni el código completo, sólo la parte exacta que no te funciona y que, una vez solucionado, te ayude a seguir con tu proyecto. En tu código sólo he visto generación de URLs aleatorias para unas imágenes pero no le veo sentido alguno a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Cuál es tu versión de php?

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con el comentario de @OscarGarcia, no obstante mirando así por encima tu página veo el problema que planteas en la captura. Parece ser que tienes un problema a la hora de asignarle la ruta a las imágenes en los atributos `<img src=undefined>`, además no cierras bien dichas etiquetas.

Adjunto una captura donde lo verás más claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es dividir tu problema en pasos más pequeños e ir formulando las preguntas para resolver estos pasos. Yo, en tu lugar, iría primero en búsqueda de como, donde y cuando se le asignan las rutas a dichas etiquetas y asegurándome que las cierras correctamente. Si no, como es normal, no vas a ver las imágenes que esperabas.

Seguramente la ruta 
    `$carpeta = "images/random";//Carpeta con las imagenes`
no es correcta, bien sea por estar definida de forma *relativa* o *absoluta* al `path` en que se encuentra el archivo que lo llama. Pero, repito, sería mejor si pudieras mirar de reproducir tu problema de un modo más concreto y minimizado que pudiéramos resolver desde aquí, sin necesidad de ver tu página.

Saludos